# How to Inherit a list of python class object into a class?

Tags: python

I have a list of class object like this,

```
cls_list = [cls_object1,cls_object2,cls_object3]
```

which is created by using `__import__` and `getattr`

how i can get all the functions inside those classes(cls_object1,cls_object2,cls_object3) in to one new class(new_class),
i tried

```
class new_class([cls_object1,cls_object2,cls_object3]):
```

but not working.

Comment: Do you actually want to type the names into the class definition?  You can just do `class New_class(cls_object1, cls_object2, cls_object3)`.

Comment: i want to add more functionality temporarily into a class of core library without re-writing it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `type(name, bases, dict)` to create a new class with a list of class as bases.

```
new_class = type("new_class", cls_list, {})
```

https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#type

Comment: i am getting an error `TypeError: a new-style class can't have only classic bases`  any idea why this error raises?

Comment: @Jake `new_class = type("new_class", cls_list+[object], {})` [new-style class](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#new-style-and-classic-classes) need `object` as it's bases.